# Table's inner border do not stretch entire table in Internet Explorer 9 (IE 9)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer, html-table

I am using an [Angular Responsive Table](https://github.com/awerlang/angular-responsive-tables) plugin for my table. Initially, it was not working on IE 9, but thanks to another SO member, I was able to fix it for IE 9 by adding 'float: left' to table's elements. Now, in IE 9, the inner table border does not go all the way, instead, it stops right after the text in the right column ends. (Might be hard to see in the pic).

[image]

CSS

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
    .table tbody tr td { float: left; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" wt-responsive-table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Version</th>
            <th>Language</th>
            <th>Maintainer</th>
            <th>Stars</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.projects">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.version}}</td>
            <td>{{item.language}}</td>
            <td>{{item.maintainer}}</td>
            <td>{{item.stars}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kTZvCnfHZ5AiNQITxnfi?p=preview)

On a side note, there is a jQuery plugin ([**Tablesaw: Stack only**](http://filamentgroup.github.io/tablesaw/demo/stackonly.html)) which has similar functionality, and it seems to work with IE 9 out of the box with no issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since floated elements only grow as big as their content, you need to set width explicit for them to stretch, so if you change your CSS like this it will work.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 800px) {
    .table tbody tr td {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;

    }
    .table {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked, but now the border flows outside the table.

Comment: I added 'overflow: hidden;' to my table and that fixed it. Edit: You modified your answer as I was writing the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Ali Updated my answer